# Function that can return something or nothing

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to define a function in Kotlin where you can either return something or return nothing? I thought maybe to use Any as the return type, but that still requires the function to return something, although perhaps there is a way to return a Unit when the return type is Any?

I also found "Nothing":

> Nothing has no instances. You can use Nothing to represent "a value that never exists": for example, if a function has the return type of Nothing, it means that it never returns (always throws an exception).

Unfortunately that will throw an exception. That's too bad. I wonder why they throw an exception?

Comment: You could return a nullable type and let `null` represent "no value". Or you could return a non-nullable type and have the function throw an exception when there's no value to return.

Comment: Someone may be able to provide you with a suitable solution if they knew what the use case was. Reading the question I would normally recommend sealed class but I don't know if that fits your usecase.

Comment: `Nothing` doesn't throw an Exception. It is a return type that means the function has no return value, which is only possible if the function throws an Exception. There are no instances of `Nothing` so it cannot actually be returned. When it comes to type inference, Nothing is treated like a subtype of everything. Kotlin needs a type like `Nothing` so branching expressions like if/else or when can have branches that throw an exception without affecting what the resultant type of the expression is. It also has use with generics variance.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the result in a sealed class

```
sealed class Result<out T> {
    data class Success<out T>(val value: T): Result<T>()
    object Failure: Result<Nothing>()
}
```

Then for calling it you can

```
fun <Type>calculateResult(...): Result<Type> {
   //calculate and return some implementation
}
```

And then

```
val result = calculateResult(inputs)
when (result) {
   is Success -> {
       val value = success.value
   }
   is Failure -> {
       //Do something like show an error the user you know your value is Nothing
   }

}
```

Comment: You can't have Nothing as a constructor parameter or give it a default value because it can hold no value. The sealed class example would make more sense if `value` were defined only in the `Success` class. The `success` class as it is cannot be a data class because it has a non-property constructor parameter.

Comment: @Tenfour04 partial yes, it should be enough for OP to see if it works or not.

Comment: If they're new to Kotlin, they may struggle with making that compilable because it has multiple errors.

Comment: @Tenfour04 that is a good observation, would mind transforming it into an edit?

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks, I like the usage of `out`, very on spot, I would have totally missed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a nullable return type.

Otherwise, to address whether you can return `Unit`, you can. `Unit` is just a Kotlin object so you can get the instance by name:

```
return Unit
```

However I wouldn't recommend it, there are plenty of better options.

In regards to `Nothing`, it is a special type that is used to represent a function never returning. So if I wanted to write a function that throws an exception, I could do so with the `Nothing` return type. Then the inference engine knows that nothing past my function call will get executed.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you think about it, a function can't return something **or** nothing, because what's the result of calling it? Do you have a value, or nothing at all? If you assign the result to a variable, but there is no result, that variable has no value, so what is it? The function has to either be defined as always returning **something** or always returning **nothing**, so you always know if there's a return value and what its possible types are. Otherwise we're getting into philosophical territory!

In fact in Kotlin, functions always return **something** - if you don't specify a type, like a `void` function in Java, it will default to returning `Unit`. This is a special value that *represents* a function not returning a result, but it *is* still a result type that gets returned. It's not *nothing*, it's a *a thing*. Every function has to return a thing.

So if you want to define the thing you return as *either* "a value that represents a thing" *or* "a value that represents nothing", you need a type that is capable of expressing both those ideas. You have three basic approaches I think:

- use a specific value to represent "no value", e.g. -1 for an `Int`, "NO_VALUE" for a `String`, that kind of thing
- create a type that defines a "no value" version of itself, like the `Result` type in one of the answers, the `Optional` type in Java, etc
- just use `null` because nullable versions of every type are built into Kotlin's type system, and the standard library is geared towards handling them. [Check out these features built around working with nulls](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html)

Use the nullable types IMO - return a `String?` or whatever and if the result is non-null, do something with the value. If it is null, ignore it. Kotlin makes that pretty easy! If you get to the point where you need to roll a special type, you'll probably know why you need it over your good friend `null`